# Why does $g^p = mN + 1$?

Tags: proof-explanation

In this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lvTqbM5Dq4Q at 5:20, he says that: If you have a number, $N$, and a smaller number that is not a factor, $g$, you can raise $g$ to some power, $p$, so that it is equal to a multiple of $N$ plus one.

$g^p = mN + 1$. I have searched for a proof for this but have been unable to find one. Could anyone explain this or let me know where I can read more. Thank you :)

Comment: This is not quite true (assuming you intended $p>0$).  If, say, $g=4$ and $N=6$ then there is no such $p$ for example.  A necessary and sufficient requirement is that $\gcd(g,N)=1$.

Comment: For the claim with the added condition, see [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem).

Comment: @lulu, it says, $g$ is not a factor of $N$, or alternatively, what you have mentioned

Comment: @user675453  In my example, $g=4$ is not a factor of $N=6$.  You really need the $\gcd$ condition which is not stated in this post.

Comment: Oh, right. Dumb mistake...